# Why is my StatelessSession asking for a container transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have a runnable task as follows

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Task(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void run() {
        StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // ... the rest is irelevant because beginTransaction launches an exception
```

SessionFactory is supplied by a bean but when I try to begin the transaction, even tough I marked the class as TransactionAttributeType.NEVER, hibernate launches the exception

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not register synchronization for container transaction
```

I tried [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=972434) but I only got another problem

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not find UserTransaction in JNDI [java:comp/UserTransaction]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateless session do not require transactions, remove the transaction statements ant try. You can read up more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html)

> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor
>   interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement
>   transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do
>   operations cascade to associated instances.

Comment: But that raises the question: is my session opening a transaction every time I insert a entity? And why is that Hibernate's own tutorial on stateless sessions mentions beginning and commiting a transaction?